# CUDA max threads in a block

Tags: cuda

I have a confusion from the programming guide . It states the following:

- maxThreadsPerBlock: 512
- maxThreadsDim: 512, 512, 64 .

When max number of threads in a block can be 512, how can the max thread dimension be 512*512*64 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392250/understanding-cuda-grid-dimensions-block-dimensions-and-threads-organization-si

Comment: what Sergey said plus: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_1/toolkit/docs/NVIDIA_CUDA_C_ProgrammingGuide_3.1.pdf

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Maximum threads in X direction: 512 (1024 for compute capability >= 2.0)

Maximum threads in Y direction: 512 (1024 for compute capability >= 2.0)

Maximum threads in Z direction:  64

So you can launch the following block configurations (compute capability >= 2.0 shown in parentheses)

- 512 x 1 x 1  (1024 x 1 x 1)
- 128 x 2 x 2  (256 x 2 x 2)
- 1 x 512 x 1  (1 x 1024 x 1)
- 1 x 8 x 64   (2 x 8 x 64)
- 2 x 4 x 64   (4 x 4 x 64)

and so on.

The total number of threads in a block must not exceed 512 (for compute capability < 2.0), or 1024 (for compute capability >= 2.0).

Comment: Reference: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications