# Timestamp in GPU

Tags: cuda, timestamp, nvidia, instrumentation, nvprof

I'm looking to collect a trace of events that take place at the device level on GPU.

**Background / Analogy on CPU:**

On a CPU, when a process A is running, it might be interrupted by another user-level process B, system/kernel processes, various kinds of interrupts such as hardware interrupts, network interrupts, hypervisor related interrupts, etc. To measure these, I would ideally have to make a kernel patch which would capture the start and end times of all processes and interrupts in the scheduler and interrupt tray. Make these kernel data structures visible to the user-level, and then read them repeatedly from a user-level program.

I want to do something similar for the GPU. ***How do I capture the timestamps of these interrupts and background processes?*** In the literature I saw that `nvidia-smi` can be used for gathering timestamp, but I'm very unclear on how to actually instrument the GPU to get what I need.

Can anybody point out references or tell me how to ***instrument*** the GPU to get timestamps? Or specifically, use `nvprof`, `cuda-memcheck` for the same purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You can get timestamps using [clock() or clock64() functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#time-function). You can use these e.g. to [capture start and end times of blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46660053/is-blockidx-correlated-to-the-order-of-block-execution/46674306#46674306) and learn how the block scheduler works.

You can also instrument your code to time specific parts of your kernels. [This can be used to gain a surprising amount of insight](http://www.stuffedcow.net/files/gpuarch-ispass2010.pdf) into the internal workings of the GPU.

In the early days of CUDA I used this a lot when tuning code. However nowadays the [nvvp profiler](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-visual-profiler) is so good that manual code instrumentation is rarely needed.

Note however that SMs don't have interrupts in the same way as CPUs do. Newer GPUs are able to suspend long-running kernels to allow the GUI to remain interactive, especially during debugger sessions. But there are no interrupts to handle I/O or for scheduling, because I/O hardware is all managed by the host, and scheduling is performed entirely in hardware. Similarly there are no background processes, because such tasks are much better handled by the CPU.